# Automatically run qacct on job completion

Tags: sungridengine

I'd like to add a line to many qsub script which will run qacct for the job that has just completed. I realise I can do this after the fact with

```
qacct -j jobid
```

but I'd like to have it done automatically. The issue I'm having is parsing the job I'd before it's submitted. Is it possible to wildcard the job ID in some way?

Comment: why not just send job emails with `-m bea` in your job script?

Answer (score 0):

According to manual for `qsub` the job id is available from within a script via the JOB_ID variable:

```
JOB_ID              A unique   identifier   assigned   by   the
                    sge_qmaster(8)  when  the  job was submitted.
                    The job ID is a decimal integer in the  range
                    1 to 99999.
```

http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html

So at the end of your script just add:

```
qacct -j $JOB_ID
```